# Can I run a batch file when I open my html document

Tags: html

I am trying to get a batch file to load in my head tag when I open my document

I have tried these and they don't seem to work:

```
<head onLoad="shutdown.bat">

<head onLoad="window.open('shutdown.bat')">
```

I've tried this as well putting it in to a function then calling it on load up

```
<head onLoad="shut">
<script>
  function shut() {
    <a href="shutdown.bat"> </a>
  }
</script>
</head>
```

I have made sure the batch file works by opening it as well

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible to do when you are opening your HTML file through `file:///` on your local computer. As soon as you host it on a server it will throw an error.

What you want to do though is this:

`window.open("file:"///C:/Path/To/File/some_bat_file.bat"`

Comment: So I do this <head onLoad="window.open("file:'C:\Users\03Daniel06\Desktop\pop ups\shutdown.bat'">